# как использовать onReady или что нибудь взамен в 3 версии braintree ( creditcard )

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, angular

Версия 2

```js
connectCreditCard(clientToken: string, paymentType: string, orderCallBack: any) {
    const wrapStoreCheckOutId = this.storeCheckOutId.bind(this);

    braintree.setup(clientToken, 'custom', {
      id: 'credit-card-form',
      hostedFields: {
        number: {
          selector: '#card-number'
        },
        cvv: {
          selector: '#cvv'
        },
        expirationDate: {
          selector: '#expiration-date'
        },
        styles: {
          'input': {
            'font-size': '18px'
          },
          '.valid': {
            'color': 'green',
            'font-weight': 'bold'
          },
          '.invalid': {
            'color': 'red',
            'font-weight': 'bold'
          },
        }
      },
      onReady: function (integration) {
        wrapStoreCheckOutId(integration);
      },
      onPaymentMethodReceived: function (paymentObject) {
        orderCallBack(paymentType, paymentObject.nonce);
      }
    });
  }

  storeCheckOutId(checkoutObj: any) {
    this.checkOutId = checkoutObj;
  }

}
```

Версия 3

```js
  connectCreditCard(clientToken: string, paymentType: string, orderCallBack: any) {
    const wrapStoreCheckOutId = this.storeCheckOutId.bind(this)
    braintree.client.create({
      authorization: clientToken
    }).then(function (clientInstance) {
      return braintree.hostedFields.create({
        client: clientInstance,
        styles: {
          'input': {
            'font-size': '18px'
          },
          '.valid': {
            'color': 'green',
            'font-weight': 'bold'
          },
          '.invalid': {
            'color': 'red',
            'font-weight': 'bold'
          }
        },
        fields: {
          number: {
            selector: '#card-number'
          },
          cvv: {
            selector: '#cvv'
          },
          expirationDate: {
            selector: '#expiration-date'
          },
        }
      })
    }).then(async function (hostedFieldsInstance) {
      let form = await document.querySelector('#creditCardForm');


      await form.addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        await hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize().then(async function (payload) {
          return orderCallBack(paymentType, payload.nonce)
        })
      })
    }, false)
 
  }

  storeCheckOutId(checkoutObj: any) {
    this.checkOutId = checkoutObj
  }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте задать этот вопрос на en.so. braintree у нас малоизвестен (я сам о нём прочёл на en.so в пятницу)

Comment: @nörbörnën а что такое en.so ? )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/braintree